# Add MS Access table data to SQL Server table with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ms-access

I have a MS Access file with a `Number` table. Also I have a SQL Server database with a `profile` table.

How do I import data from the `number` table into the `profile` table?

Comment: do you want to convert your ms access database to sql server(mdf) db file?

Comment: no , i want add info to exist table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
    const string connectionString = "YOUR ACCESS CONNECTION STRING";
    const string connectionStringDest = "YOUR SQL SERVER CONNECTION STRING";
    using (var sourceConnection =
          new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sourceConnection.Open();

        var commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand(
            "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_X;", sourceConnection);
        var reader =
            commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

        using (var destinationConnection =
                   new SqlConnection(connectionStringDest))
        {
            destinationConnection.Open();

            using (var bulkCopy =
                       new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                    "dbo.TABLE_DEST";

                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: error is : Syntax error in FROM clause.
this error yellow   `var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

Comment: I do not know your table structure so i put an example one

Comment: "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_X;" to  "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_X"  semicalon is ?

Comment: please see :http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/574384/SyntaxpluserrorplusinplusFROMplusclause